# Error while running a CNN-LSTM model: ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_13 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, lstm, conv-neural-network

I am receiving an error while running the below code:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=max_length),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')
   ])
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_13 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 128]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()` with `tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling1D()`

Comment: Any particular reason?

Comment: yes... you have to maintain the 3d dimension for the LSTM layer. It's work?